# Search result and export to excel using laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

any one can checked, where did i get wrong and why i get empty record during downloading. please take alook my code.

```
    public function selloutitem_search(Request $request)
    {
        $dstart = $request->get('dstart');
        $dstop = $request->get('dstop');
        $cat = $request->get('cat');
        $branch = $request->get('branch');

        $ddstart = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dstart));  
        $ddstop = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dstop));  

        $Sellout = DB::table('Sellout')
                ->Where('custom2',$cat)
                ->Where('Code',$branch)
                ->whereBetween('docket_date',[$ddstart, $ddstop])
                //->orderBy('description', 'asc');
                //->paginate(100);
                ->get();

          foreach ($Sellout as $order) 
          {
                $data[] = array(
                    "Barcode"=> $order->Barcode,
                );
          }

        return Excel::download($data, 'report.xlsx');
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors?

Comment: no error at all, but i get empty excel file.

Comment: What `dd($Sellout)` prints?

Comment: i get the correct result of all data. but in excel is empty.